# Multisampling Gamma Correction Problem

Tags: xna-4.0, antialiasing, multisampling

I have multisampled rendertarget where I use red channel as stencil data, but the problem is I get incorrect results around borders if "Antialiasing - Gamma Correction" is set to *on* in Nvidia Control Panel. Is there a way to turn that off while writing to that specific render target (if user has it enabled in graphics card's control panel)?

This is with XNA 4.0.